# fileinfo, datagridview, file.exist

Tags: c#, datagridview, fileinfo

please can anyone help me i'm still figuring C# out, I have on my main form a datagridview and currently saves the uploaded files info there, but i want to do a check to see if the file exists don't upload if it does upload but honestly i'm struggling to understand the differences between fileinfo, directoryinfo, and how to work with it please have a look at my code,
Thanks in advance!

```
string sqlSt = "Insert into Documents (CategoryID, PathofDocument,DocumentName,FileSize,FileExtension,AddedBy,LastActioned) values (@CategoryID,@FilePath,@FileName,@FileSize,@FileExtension,@AddedBy,@LastActioned)";


            OpenFileDialog fi = new OpenFileDialog();
            //DialogResult result = fi.ShowDialog();
            fi.Filter = "allfiles (*.*)|*.* |Text files(*.txt)|*.txt | Excel Files (*.xls)| *.xls |EmailFiles (*.msg) | *.msg";
            string fileio = fi.FileName;
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileio);



                if (fi.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    if (file.Exists(,fileio))
                    { }

                //    MessageBox.Show("File Already exist" + file.FullName);

                }
                else

                    if (file.Exists != true)
                    {
                        using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(Connstring))
                        {
                            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSt, Conn))
                            {
                                Conn.Open();
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CategoryID", treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", Path.GetFullPath(fi.FileName));
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", Path.GetFileName(file.Name));
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileSize", file.Length / 1024);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileExtension", file.Extension);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddedBy", UserCon.Text);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastActioned", file.LastAccessTime);
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                SetValueforAddedB = UserCon.Text;
                                SetValueforType = Typtxt.Text;
                                Conn.Close();
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to setup your variables before getting the user choice

Comment: Please explain better what you want to do. This code runs an insert in the database if the user CANCELS the OpenFileDialog. It doesn't seem to be correct. Also, if the file EXISTS what you want to do? There is no UPLOAD code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`File` has a static method which you can use to see if a file exists.

```
if (File.Exists("path"))
{
    // upload code
}
else
{
    // show message or whatever
}
```

> i'm struggling to understand the differences between fileinfo, directoryinfo

`FileInfo` is used for interacting and doing work on files. `DirectoryInfo` is used for interacting and doing work with folders (directories).

If you are performing a single operation on a file, then use the static class `File`. The same goes for `Directory`. However, if you are doing multiple operations such as check if file exists, then read the file, then change the file, then save the file, then in that case use `FileInfo`.

`File` and `Directory` are static classes. `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` are non static so you can create an instance, keep the instance and do all the operations on the instance.

Comment: i did try that as well but if i declare the path i need to set it to a value and i want it to be set to the path of the file that the user chose

Comment: Just use `if(File.Exists(fi.FileName))`

Comment: Thank you so much that makes sense